# '@ts-expect-error' typescript directive not working inside a jest test

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, nomachine-nx

I'm creating an express app using nx and axiom.
Now, I'm trying to use the //@ts-expect-error directive , but I've got the error
Unused '@ts-expect-error' directive  both from my terminal and my editor.

this is my test:

```
describe('apps', () => {
  it('should return an error if you return things not in the ts 
    definition', () => {
     expect(() => {
        appNotify.get('/v1/notify/healthcheck', ( res) => {
            //@ts-expect-error - notExistingProperty shold not be allowed
            res.json({
                notExistingProperty: true,
                message: 'Welcome to notify!' 
            });

          
          });
    }).toThrow();
  });
});
```

this is my tsconfig :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@notify/logger": ["libs/logger/src/index.ts"],
      "@notify/notify-redis-client": ["libs/notify-redis-client/src/index.ts"]
    },
    "strict": true
    },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

my typescript version is 4.9.5

I've tryied enabling checkJS in the tsconfig but nothing changed.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing - test that TypeScript doesn't like passing in an invalid parameter. I think the problem is that TypeScript checks are done at compile type and Jest does runtime testing.